# Should I report z-score, p-value or both for Mann-Whitney U test under APA guidelines?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, reporting

As titled, I ran a MWU test on my test results but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to report. My results section currently looks like this. Help?
[image]

Comment: Here is an incantation to ward off close-voters: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3132/1352

Comment: Have you checked whether this particular test is covered in the *APA Publication Manual*?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you report the statistic ($U$) and the $p$ value. That is usually sufficient. If the reviewers want $z$ scores or anything else as well, they will tell you. But that should be enough information to get past the first hurdle.

And of course, I would recommend that you check the *APA Publication Manual*, which I don't have with me, but which may indeed cover this particular test in its sheer comprehensiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan's answer is pretty good, but APA also recommends reporting standardized effect sizes, even though sometimes they're not as important as they seem to be. Looks like you have the $r$ value that pertains to the $z$ approximation to the $U$ statistic, which is discussed in this [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21823805/) by Fritz, Morris, & Richler (2012) as a good effect size measure to use.